# A grounded number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

There is no external source required, this relies only on maths.

Each line is independent from the others.
Can you find the pattern and fill in the blanks ?

```
1 : 0 0 0
2 : 1 2 3
3 : 4 2 9 
4 : 1 2 3
5 : 7 7 9
6 : 4 0 6
7 : 2 4 9
8 : _ _ _
9 : 7 5 8
10: 5 9 5
11: _ _ _
12: _ _ _
```

**Hint :**

> `_A_B_C________________________________________________...`

`_` stands for 1 digit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

8:

> 9 8 9

11:

> 4 5 5

12:

> 3 0 5

The numbers are

> the first three odd decimal digits of n^(1/n). For example, 2 gives us 1,4**1**4**2**1**3**...

Comment: what the...? how did you end up looking in that direction?

Comment: Well, it was a small step from "grounded" to "roots", the missing sequence for 8 8pointed me towards cubic roots initially, which worked with 3, but not the others... it was not too hard to connect the dots from there on.